How do I declare a custom tag in R Shiny?
I would like to declare a custom tag in my R shiny app.
I have tried this:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  tags$my-tag(id = "my-tag")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

But it creates an error
Error in tag(id = "my-tag") : unused argument (id = "my-tag")

Any suggestions?

Have a look at how it is build in shiny running: shiny::tags$b by example. You have to create your own function

I see, but I had a look here: https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/latest/builder.html and it seems that Shiny supports custom tags already?

Is it what you want: shiny::tag("custom", varArgs = list("id" = "my-tag"), .noWS = NULL, .renderHook = NULL)

In addition to @Clemsang's advice, "my-tag" is a valid HTML id but is not a valid R identifier.  Your line tags$my-tag(id = "my-tag") gets parsed as tags$my - tag(id = "my-tag") and id is not a valid parameter name for shiny::tag...

Not that I'd recommend it, but you create something like:
library(htmltools)

`my-tag` <- function(..., .noWS = NULL, .renderHook = NULL) {
  tag("my-tag", list(...), .noWS, .renderHook)
}

`my-tag`(id = "myid")
# <my-tag id="myid"></my-tag>

I'd give `my-tag` a valid R name (my_tag say) and use it the same way. But as shown you can also use non syntactical names, if you include them in backticke `.

From htmltools package, reexpeported by shiny, without additional function:
tag("my-tag", varArgs = list("id" = "my-tag-id"))
# <my-tag id="my-tag-id"></my-tag>


tag is in fact a htmltools:: function which is simply re-exported to  shiny

Jut edited thanks!
